# The volume primary SSD could not be repaired

Tags: hard-drive

My machine is not starting after progress bar. I'm trying to find the problem by booting in single user mode.

I tried `/sbin/fsck -fy`

It showed me 
`Missing directory record (id = 33899953)` 
`The volume Primary SSD could not be repaired`

Answer (score 2):

Boot to Recovery HD, open in the menubar Utilities > Terminal. Enter `df` to get the name of your main volume (e.g. "Macintosh HD").

Enter `diskutil verifyVolume /Volumes/Vol_name` (e.g. `diskutil verifyVolume "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"`).

Then repair the volume with `diskutil repairVolume /Volumes/Vol_name`.

If no main volume is mounted try `diskutil list`, determine the disk identifier of the main volume (e.g. disk0s2) and first enter `diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk0` and repair it if necessary with `diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk0`, then `diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s2` and repair it with `diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk0s2`.

If your SSD has a CoreStorage Logical Volume Group  `diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk0` should already repair everything.

If this fails you usually have to use some third-party software like DiskWarrior to repair the volume or restore a (Time Machine-)backup.

Comment: On running `df` it showed me following http://4.1m.yt/48uuHrG.jpg

Comment: @Freddy Answer updated

Comment: For each of them it shows `The volume 176 .... 0E appears to be OK`  and `File system check exit code is 0`

Comment: @Freddy Already tried to boot to your main system volume again?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't work....should I try repair?

Comment: @Freddy If `diskutil verifyDisk/verifyVolume ...`s' exit codes are zero, you are left with the last two options: DiskWarrior or restore a backup...